# get array name from multilevel array in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

how i can get `WP_Widget_Archives` from array,

This is my array:

```
$control = Array
(
    [name] => Archives
    [id] => archives-6
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Widget_Archives Object
                (
                    [id_base] => archives
                    [name] => Archives
                    [widget_options] => Array
                        (
                            [classname] => widget_archive
                            [description] => A monthly archive of your site’s Posts.
                        )

                    [control_options] => Array
                        (
                            [id_base] => archives
                        )

                    [number] => 8
                    [id] => archives-8
                    [updated] => 
                    [option_name] => widget_archives
                )

            [1] => form_callback
        )

    [params] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [number] => 6
                )

        )

    [width] => 250
    [height] => 200
    [id_base] => archives
)
```

i have try with this code

```
`echo '<pre>'; print_r(array_keys($control['callback'])); echo '</pre>';`
```

but I get result like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

where I think the result will be like this

```
$result = Array
(
    [0] => WP_Widget_Archives Object
    [1] => form_callback
)
```

so i can write `$result[0]` for get `WP_Widget_Archives`, please help me and thank you for your help :)

Comment: Just don't get the keys and just the values. Remove the `array_keys()` call

Comment: ty for comment, i have try but i get all of WP_Widget_Archives child array element. What i need just to get "WP_Widget_Archives " word as string

Comment: Then you need to call `get_class()` on the object.

Comment: oh, thank you its work

Answer (score 0):

Probably you misunderstood array_key function. It will give you keys of the array not value. In your case you require value which is an object 'WP_Widget_Archives', so you can directly use $control['callback'][0].